# The Vacisek Model and the short rate process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am trying to do some calculations related to the Vacisek model, but I think I am mixing up concepts and I'm not getting to any solution. Let me explain what the problem is.

The Vacisek model follows the SDE $$dR_t = -a(R_t-b)dt + \sigma dW_t$$
with $R_0 = r_0$, with $a, b, \sigma > 0$ and $(W_t : t \in [0,T])$ is a Brownian Motion with filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_{t}\}_{t\geq0}$. It can be shown that the solution to this SDE is
$$
R_t = b +(r_0 - b)e^{-at} + \sigma \int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}dW_s
$$

Now, **assuming** **that** $a = 0$, I would like to compute
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_t^T R_sds - M_t  \right)^2 \middle| \mathscr{F}_t\right] \mbox{     for $t \leq T$}
$$

where $M_t = \mathbb E\left[\int_t^T R_sds \middle| \mathscr{F}_t\right]$.

I have started by doing the following:
$$
\mathbb E\left[\int_t^T R_sds \middle| \mathscr{F}_t\right] = 
\mathbb E\left[\int_t^T r_0 + \sigma W_sds \middle| \mathscr{F}_t\right]
$$

My problem is how to move forward from here, the conditional expectation is making me doubt whether I should have taken a different approach. Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0$, then $R_s=r_0+\sigma W_s$ for every $s$ hence 
$$
K_T=\int_t^TR_s\mathrm ds=(T-t)(r_0+\sigma W_t)+\sigma\int_0^{T-t}V_s\mathrm ds,
$$ 
where $V=(W_{t+s}-W_t)_{s\geqslant0}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_t$. Thus, $M_T=E(K_T\mid\mathcal F_t)$ is
$$
M_T=(T-t)(r_0+\sigma W_t)+\sigma\int_0^{T-t}E(V_s)\mathrm ds=
(T-t)(r_0+\sigma W_t),
$$
and
$$
K_T-M_T=\sigma\int_0^{T-t}V_s\mathrm ds,
$$
is independent of $\mathcal F_t$. Thus,
$$
E((K_T-M_T)^2\mid\mathcal F_t)=E((K_T-M_T)^2)=u(T-t),
$$
where, for every nonnegative $\tau$,
$$
u(\tau)=\sigma^2\iint_{[0,\tau]^2}E(V_sV_u)\mathrm ds\mathrm du=\sigma^2\int_0^{\tau}\int_0^u2s\mathrm ds\mathrm du=\frac13\sigma^2\tau^3.$$

Comment: looking at your answer, I am trying to understand the way you solved the integral $\int_t^T R_s ds$ and ended up with a $(T-t)$-dependent expression. Is it a change of variables? Why did you follow this strategy? I do not follow those first calculations.

Comment: Simply integrate the identity $R_{t+s}=r_0+\sigma W_{t+s}=r_0+\sigma W_t+\sigma V_{s}$ from $s=0$ to $s=T-t$.